# CSS - Positioning Conundrum

Tags: html, css

I'm working with absolute positioning within a relative div.  The code is as such: http://jsfiddle.net/32mq5v6L/1/

HTML

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="featured-posts">
        <div class="slide"><img src="http://alien.devprose.com/starwars/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/star-wars-droid.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="http://alien.devprose.com/starwars/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/han-solo-1140x350.jpg" /></div>
    </div>

    <div id="other-content">
    Other Content
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#container { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; background: #eee; }

#featured-posts { position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto;}
.slide { width: 100%; height: 20px; position: absolute; top: 0; }

#other-content { }
```

My problem is the other-content div appears underneath #featured-posts unless I apply a set height to that container, which I can't do since the goal is to make all of this responsive.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Absolute positioning and responsive design don't play nicely together. How are you intending for this to look? Are you just trying to show only one post at a time?

Comment: I think you should trying doing what you're trying to do with the slides using float instead of absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have `#other-content` after positioned container, you will have to create new stacking context in order to move it above. One way to do it since it's not positioned is to set very little opacity:

```css
#other-content {
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: .99;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/32mq5v6L/1/